# Migration from Dojo 1.3.1 to 1.9.3

Tags: javascript, dojo, migration

I've a project in which front-end is developed using dojo 1.3.1 and there are around 100+ custom widgets and dojo files.
My task is to migrate all the code from **Dojo 1.3.1** to **Dojo 1.9.3**(latest till date).

I've tried to replace the Dojo 1.3.1 source with 1.9.3 but everything breaks and I cannot see anything on UI. Obviously this is because of the major syntax differences between the two versions, specifically the changes in syntax of defining modules and including modules.

Is this the only way that I've to change the syntax in all the 100+ files and check if the functionality + UI works or there could be another better workaround for this?

**EDIT:**
I've used dojo-amd-converter to convert custom modules from pre-AMD to AMD. There is one file which is converted as follows:

Old Code:

```
dojo.provide("myModule.objects");
dojo.require("dojo._base");

myModule.objects.psCookie = (
    function () {
        // Default Values
        var defaultArgs = {
            ident: "",
            email: ""
        }
        return function(args) {
            return myModule.objects.cleanArgs(args, defaultArgs);
        }
    }
)();
```

Converted Code:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base",
    "dojo/_base/lang"
], function (_base, lang) {

    myModule.objects.psCookie = (
        function () {
            // Default Values
            var defaultArgs = {
                ident: "",
                email: ""
            }
            return function(args) {
                return myModule.objects.cleanArgs(args, defaultArgs);
            }
        }
    )();
```

Now, I'm facing couple of issues after conversion:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/td/js/dojo-release-1.9.3/dojo/_base.js 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'psCookie' of undefined /td/js/myModule/objects.js:6
```

Any idea how I can resolve these issues?

Comment: While Dojo 1.7+ supports AMD, it also continues to support the old APIs, so things shouldn't entirely break.  Without some specific examples of the kinds of errors you're running into, this question is way too broad to address.  You might want to look at the [release notes](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/releasenotes/) for each version of Dojo for clues.

Comment: I agree with @KenFranqueiro. Without code and/or errors we simply cannot help you.

Comment: @KenFranqueiro I've updated my question, please see if you can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things here, to resolve the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/td/js/dojo-release-1.9.3/dojo/_base.js 404 (Not Found)
```

You just have to remove `dojo/_base` from your module list, for example:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/lang"
], function (lang) {
    // Rest of your code
});
```

Then, the whole `dojo.provide()` system is gone, so that means there is no object provided for you as a module anymore (so you get an error that that object is `undefined`). In stead of that, you just return an object by yourself, for example:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/lang"
], function(lang) {
    return {
        psCookie: /** Your code */
    };
});
```

However, I'm not really familiar about what the `psCookie` does in your example, so you might have to explain that a bit further.

Comment: I will remove the "dojo/_base" dependency, but will there be any effect after removing this?

Comment: It depends on what you use. `dojo.require("dojo._base")` probably included everything of the `dojo/_base` package. So if you're using anything from it, then it means you have to import the modules explicitely, for example `dojo/_base/lang`, `dojo/_base/declare`, `dojo/_base/array`, ... .